# Obtener URL carro woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

como podría añadirle al icono de mi carrito en woocommerce el enlace a mi página de carrito¿??

```
<div class="unit unit-spacing-xs-4 align-items-center">
  <div class="unit-body">
    <a href="<?php// $cart_url = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url(); ?>">
      <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart fa-2x"> </i>
    </a>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Todo el PHP, añado código que estaba usando, pero no funciona

tengo mi plantilla cart.php pero no se bien como hacer esta plantilla.

Me pueden echar un cable¿?

en **functions.php** he dado soporte para esto

```
add_filter('woo_cart_but', 'woo_cart_but');
function woo_cart_but() {
    ob_start();

        $cart_count = WC()->cart->cart_contents_count; // Set variable for cart item count
        $cart_url = wc_get_cart_url();  // Set Cart URL

        ?>
        <li><a class="menu-item cart-contents" href="<?php echo $cart_url; ?>" title="My Basket">
        <?php
            if ( $cart_count > 0 ) {
                ?>
                    <span class="cart-contents-count"><?php echo $cart_count; ?></span>
                <?php
            }
        ?>
        </a>
        </li>
        <?php

return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Agradezco toda ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se entiende muy bien que es lo que quieres hacer, el filtro woo_cart_but no es de woocommerce.

Si ya tienes el código dónde imprimes tu ícono, supongo que en la cabecera del sitio, solo tienes que imprimir la url del carrito en la línea:

```
// esta línea
<a href="<?php// $cart_url = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url(); ?>">
// la cambias por esta
<a href="<?php echo wc_get_cart_url(); ?>">
```